# Display google map in bootstrap page when javascript is used on the map

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

I have created a basic html 5 page. I have successfully integrated google map and added some javascript so that when a user clicks on the map, a marker appears at that particular location.
Now I am trying to make this page responsive by using bootstrap.
The map is no more appearing on the page. I have been searching for these last couples of days and found that iframe can be used. Unfortunately, no tutorial, that I found, used iframes and javascript at the same time.
Can you help me please.

Here is the code I used for the map

```
<div id="map" style="width:50%;height:600px;position:left"><script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=myMap" async defer></script></div>
e
```

Comment: Just to clarify... You want that the map to be responsive, right?

Comment: show  the html code of your map page ..

Comment: exactly. so that when the window size is changed, it automatically adapts to it

Comment: @scaisEdge I modified my question and added the div. 'callback=myMap' at the end of the url is the call to the javascript

Comment: how have you defined the width of the  parent container of your map ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

And set the div width for map to 100%:

```
#map {
 width: 100%;
}
```

That should do the trick!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried it but it is still not working. The map is not showing up

Comment: No. the map is not showing up. I did the following: <div class="container">
<div id="map"><script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=myMap" async defer></script></div>
</div> and included the styling also

Comment: No need to add script tag inside map div. Put the script right before body closing tag for better performance.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial Check this page. Actually, callback parameter needs to be a function to load the map.

Comment: It makes the map responsive. Thanks a lot. But isn't there a way to use this trick with bootstrap.  I was planning to put the map on the left and a form on the right. When resized, everything is stacked.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you